# Install Mouse Driver on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, mouse

I have a mouse that I absolutely love (been using them for years), A4Tech WOP-35. It has dual scrollers and 5 buttons, 3 of the buttons are programmable. I use them at work and at home.

At work I am using Windows 7 Enterprise (32 bit), at home I am using Windows 7 Professional (64 bit).

The drivers installed easily on my machine at work. Unfortunately, they will not install on my computer at home. When I double click on the Setup.exe, it asks me if I want to install it, and of course I click on "Yes", but nothing happens.  When I say nothing happens, I mean nothing happens; it appears that it doesn't even try to install.  The same thing happens when I right click on the setup.exe and select run as administrator.

How can I get around this? I am guessing it is because I am running the 64 bit version of Windows.

Comment: Try this driver, use the x64 for vista...http://www.x7.cn/en/driver/X-7XX.zip

Comment: That mouse seems to have a very interesting design.  Could you share a screenshot of it?

Comment: *** UPDATE *** I found a picture of it here:  http://www.torent.ro/imagini/mari/78903/09b98fb3bb4b.jpg

Comment: I won't put this link as an answer because it may not work, but someone has found that the Smart X7 mouse drive works well for the WOP-49Z so it may work for your WOP-35? http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/86099-a4tech-mouse-driver.html

Answer (score 4):

You're right, it's because of your 64-bit Windows. :)  Hardware drivers are one of those things that the 64-bit vs. 32-bit addressing makes the difference, so you need 64-bit drivers.

Upon looking up your mouse, I see that A4Tech doesn't offer a driver for anything newer than Vista 32-bit.  But the [Windows driver package](http://www.a4tech.com/downloads.asp) they offer DOES contain Windows 2003 64-bit and XP 64-bit drivers, so *MAYBE* one of those will work.

Perhaps [contact A4Tech](http://www.a4tech.com/emailus.asp) for some guidance?

Comment: That was the driver I downloaded, but it doesnt want to install at all.

Comment: @Soren - That's what I figured. You're probably at the mercy of A4Tech to create an updated driver to get full functionality in newer or unsupported operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I too looked for the Windows 7 driver for other mice:

[2X-Office_X5.X6-57D.OP-57D.zip](http://www.a4tech.com/download%20driver.asp?cmodnum=X6-57D)

- Install and go to *Control Panel » Mouse*
- Choose *Mouse* and change the driver.

This mouse hadn't the second wheel but works in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe one can use a 32-bit driver on 64-bit Windows 7, except maybe in XP Mode (which is just a 32-bit virtual machine).

You can try to set the Compatibility of setup.exe to an older version of Windows and try to install, but I am afraid that this will not change much.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't acquire a 64-bit driver for Windows 7, you could try the freeware [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm).  It will let you program the functions of the various buttons.  I'm not sure how it will handle the dual scroll wheels though.

Comment: The program works good. I still dont have horizontal scrolling (no setting for the second scroller wheel), but at least I can program the buttons for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Download driver "iWheelWorks_Vista_1W3K.zip" (yeah, it is "AK-6" not "A4Tech WOP-35" but...)

http://www.a4tech.com/download%20driver.asp?cmodnum=AK-6

Unzip. Open "/Vista X64 driver/Setup.ini" change to this and save:

```
[Mouse]
Button=5
Wheel=2
MouseType=7
RFMouse=0
PowerType=0
MouseSample=0


[Version]
OEMVersion=1
HasHelp=0
```

Then install via "Setup.exe". (not my clue but it works for me)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the saveO_o works for me:
"WheelWorks_Vista_1W3K.zip
Vista X64 driver/Setup.ini" change:

[Mouse]
Button=5
Wheel=2
MouseType=7
RFMouse=0
PowerType=0
MouseSample=0

[Version]
OEMVersion=1
HasHelp=0"

Now on Win7 64-bit the all features (5 button + 2 wheel) of the WOP-35 mouse works great.

Many many thanks for saveO_o!!!